# VUEX, VUE, APOLLO - Component not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

From a child component I make a `GraphQL` request and emit the result to the parent component successfully.

Instead of storing and updating an array of results in my parent component, I've refactored this to **VUEX**.

Upon receiving a result, I dispatch an event to my store, using the `this.$store.dispatch('handle', payload)` method.

This then triggers a mutation, which successfully updates the store:

```
UPDATE_RESULT(state, result) {
    state.queries[state.search.selectedQuery].results[result.index] = {
        ...result
    }
}
```

Back in my parent component, I use the `mapState({})` helper to map my results array to a computed property. In Vue dev tools I can confirm that both the store updates, and the computed property updates on my component sucessfully:

```
computed: {
    ...mapState({
        results: state => state.queries[state.search.selectedQuery].results
    })
},
```

My template however refuses to update:

```
<template v-for="(result, index) in results">{{result}}</template>
```

I can see that the template seems to be one tick behind both the computed property, and the store. I've tried using a watcher, using getters and setters, having a local results array and copying the store to this... but nothing works, other than a setTimeout.

Pulling my hair out!!!

Comment: Can you confirm that `state.queries` is an empty object in initial state?

Comment: Thanks for your response. No this is populated with query terms and such. The results array is however empty.